# Special Characters not rendering properly on live website

Tags: 2011, templating, content-manager, configuration, rtf

I am facing issue with production website which is displaying some special characters as black diamond shape with a question mark inside, on multiple browsers .However, the QA website is displaying the same characters correctly on the same set of browsers. So, it doesn't seems to be an issue with browser not supproting the special characters because it is displaying the same characters correctly for QA website but not for live website.

Need solution for the same.Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check if on the Live publication target (in Content Manager) UTF-8 is selected as Default Code Page?

Answer (score 7):

There are normally three places that I would check for character display issues such as this:

1. Do the characters look correct inside of the Components in the Tridion Content Management Explorer (CME)?
2. Can you open the published page (assuming that this is not a Dynamic Component Presentation) in Notepad++ or similar on the web server? Do the characters look ok in here?
3. How do the characters look inside of the browser?

---

Given that the content is correct on the QA environment, I'd assume that what you're seeing in the CME (Number 1) is correct.

If the characters are not correct when you open up the published page in Notepad++ (Number 2), then it is probably that the `Default Code Page` setting is not correct on your Publishing Target.

[image]

If the characters are correct on the published page in Notepad++ (Number 2), but are not correct in the browser (Number 3) then I would normally check that the encoding used by web application.

For example:

- In the .NET **web.config**: `<globalization fileEncoding="UTF-8" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8"/>`.
- If it is Java based then I think that `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` will do this.

However, I'd assume that your application code and globalisation configuration is the same between your QA and Production environments, so it is probably not that.

Answer (score 3):

just adding to @jonathan's - Check various options available on Elena's blog. i overlooked it recently to resolved my chinese characters issue but ultimately it resolved my issue, it takes care of all options available.

http://elenaserghie.blogspot.in/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: I also have a blog which might be useful.. http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/why-cant-i-get-my-special-characters-to-display-properly