# Facing issues while rendering some special chars | DD4T.Net 1.3 | Tridion 2013Sp1

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dd4t, upgrade, encoding

We are facing issues while rendering special characters on live site after upgrading CMS from 2011 SP1 to 2013 sp1 and DD4T 1.24 to DD4T 1.3.

We are getting ã© instead of é on rendered page where as we entered the content in RTF as Café. We published that Component as DCP to file system. I can see that the content is correct in DCP XML file.

We have referred below url's 
 [Special Characters not rendering properly on live website](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13921/special-characters-not-rendering-properly-on-live-website)

http://elenaserghie.blogspot.in/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Checked our Target settings for Unicode(utf-8)

Added globalization tag in web config

Add utf-8 meta tag at page level

Comment: What happens when you use an ASCII code instead in RTF? That would help isolate the problem.

Comment: Double check the file format of the DCP XML in the file system, or keep the jvm.xml on the deployer config folder.

Comment: @shiva we are facing same problem in both cases

Comment: @Velmurugan we have checked the DCP XML is fine and also keep jvm.xml on deployer config but still facing same issue.